# Store provider error with EF

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, odp.net

I'm currently working on a MVC application which uses Entity Framework to interact with an Oracle Database.

Creating the edmx, adding and updating tables, all those actions are done without raising any error since I've installed all the Oracle providers I needed to make it work with .NET.

However, here's the thing : when I'm trying to run my app (which is done without errors), when the following line is executed, Visual Studio raises an error.

```
return PartialView("_GridViewRecruitmentPartial", model.Where(e => e.NON_ACTIVE != 1).OrderByDescending(e => e.EMPL_ID).ToList());
```

The error message :

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or
>   is not valid.

And the inner message:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed

I'm aware that something's wrong with EF and Oracle but can't see what. Plus, I've plenty of other projects using those 2 and everything went well.

Any guess?

Comment: Are you talking about an error that occurs after you DEPLOY your app to a different location than where you developed it? If so, there are required config file updates to let EF know about ODP.NET. These are handled automatically by the ODP.NET Entity Framework Nuget package or by the ODP.NET installer based install (in the second case you need to run the installer on the target machine or update the config yourself). Please confirm what is going on and what exact odp.net packages you are using, Nuget or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you using for data access. There are multiple Oracle providers... Anyway, you should probably use official [Oracle Managed driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/) from Nuget.

When you install it from Nuget it should add itself to your web.config so everything works..

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```